# Qualified API Name returns null in Test context for Custom Metadata

Tags: apex, custom-metadata, metadata-relationship

Winter 19 release provides ability to instantiate the [custom metadata in apex](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_development_custom_metadata_types_apex.htm) .This seems to be useful to generate data for test classes .

However when we have metadata relationship entity or field entity relationship the QualifiedName comes as null in Test class .

Lets take an example with the below code in a Test class .For now use execute Anonymous  via Dev console

```
Relationship__mdt relationship = new Relationship__mdt(
        DeveloperName = 'Test',
        Active__c = true,
        Object__c = 'Account',
        AccountRelationship__c = 'ParentId'
    );
 system.debug('###'+relationship.Object__r.qualifiedAPIName);
```

In the above code Object__c is of type metadataRelationship (Object definition ) and AccountRelationship__c is also of metadataRelationship type (Field Entity Definition) .

When i do `relationship.Object__r.QualifiedAPIName` in test context I receive **null** and not 'Account'.

Similarly when i do `relationship.AccountRelationship__r.QualifiedAPIName` in test context I receive null and not ParentId .

This makes it not helpful again for use cases where metadata data has entity relationship and the code uses QualifiedName .

Is it a bug or I am overlooking something ?

Comment: I've never observed this problem. What instance are you on?

Comment: Sandbox instance and note this issue is in test class

Comment: No I mean `cs10`, `cs20`, etc. Also are you actually able to construct a record or is that just pseudo-code to illustrate?

Comment: cs66 instance .

Comment: Please clarify exactly how you retrieve/create this record as it may be relevant.

Comment: Added few more explanation lines .Use execute anonymous to reproduce it .Your org needs to have a custom metadata with field linked to Object entity and a custom field .

Comment: I cant see if you have populated AccountRelationship__r = new AccountRelationships__mdt(). If its not querried then you have to pouplate it. Its same creating instance of normal sobject in SF

Comment: AccountRelationship is an object reference and not anothrt custom metadata reference .

Comment: relationships are not automatically populated, you have to query for them. Also, all the fields you need to use are read-only, so you would have to either create a big JSON string to fake the relationship, or you'll have to use the stub API/dependency injection.

Comment: I can't query because custom metadata records are always in memory .Dependency injection seems good alternative

Comment: Last I checked you could not even construct Custom Metadata records. This is the first I've seen of that change.

Comment: i tend to use Selector pattern  (for something to mock a result), github lib Sobject Fabricator (to mock the sobjects), and ApexMocks to return the mocked result for the selector so the methods under test have sobjects to work with

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You still need to use JSON construction if you want to set parent attributes without a true query for the records.

---

**Non Functional Code**

```
EntityDefinition sourceObject = [SELECT QualifiedApiName FROM EntityDefinition LIMIT 1];
MyMapping__mdt mapping = new MyMapping__mdt(
    Source_Object__r = sourceObject
);
```

**Error**

> Field is not writeable: MyMapping__mdt.Source_Object__r

---

**Functional Code**

```
Map<String, Object> mockMapping = new Map<String, Object>
{
    'attributes' => new Map<String, Object>
    {
        'type' => 'MyMapping__mdt '
    },
    'Source_Object__r' => new Map<String, Object>
    {
        'attributes' => new Map<String, Object>
        {
            'type' => 'EntityDefinition'
        },
        'QualifiedApiName' => 'Account'
    }
};
MyMapping__mdt mapping = (MyMapping__mdt)JSON.deserialize(
    JSON.serialize(mockMapping), MyMapping__mdt.class
);
system.debug(mapping.Source_Object__r.QualifiedApiName);
```

**Log**

> Account

Comment: Thanks for the response .I just feel this should be natively supported

Comment: Perhaps it will come in future releases. It was a pretty big change just to allow construction of `Custom Metadata` at all.